# Discord py send message to channel

Tags: python, bots, discord

I am trying to use discord.py library to send message from one channel to another. Idea - channel_1 user has no rights to read and send messages in channel_2. I tried to write bot which should send these messages - for example, user writes !send "channel2" "hello" and bot send this message to channel 2. But I have got an error tryong to do this

```
    import os
import random

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
token = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def xsend(ctx, *, message):
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    await ctx.send(discord.Object(id='652024045339934731'), message)

bot.run(token)
```

Error I get  - TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not discord.py-rewrite, right? So just use `bot.get_channel()` and send message by `bot.send_message()`. [Link to documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.12/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)

*(Btw, ctx.send() will send message to invoked channel, if I know right)*

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def xsend(ctx, *, message: str):
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    channel = bot.get_channel('652024045339934731')
    if channel:
        await bot.send_message(channel, message)
```

(Version for discord.py-rewrite)

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def xsend(ctx, *, message: str):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    channel = bot.get_channel(652024045339934731)
    if channel:
        await channel.send(message)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. Decided to change some functionality - user sends message to channel (with attachements and links). After that runs bot and it forwards last message to another channel as embedded message, but bot sends only text, not pictures or links... Tried to use embed.add_field: 
https://pastebin.com/p8TB4D7i 
but get an error - 'list' object has no attribute 'attachements'

Comment: There's a grammar problem. Not attach**e**ments but attachments.